# Scroll bar did't get updated the height when data changed via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar

I have some problem width a scroll bar. Here is my code,

**Css code :**

```
#content-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow-y : auto;
    overflow-x : hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML code :**

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <ul id="my-ul">
        <li>data</li>
        .
        .
    </ul>
</div
```

This work normally

But When I got new data to bind to ul as below,

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/api/somedata',
    success : function(data){
       $('#my-ul').empty();     //clear old data.
       _.each(data, function(myItem){
          $('#my-ul').append('<li>'+myItem.name+'</li>');
       });
    }
});
```

> My problem is new data that were bind to ul tag are less than the
>   older but scrollbar did't get updated. There is a empty space in
>   content-wrapper tag. It still remember the older height.

Comment: When you say `height:100%`, it will occupy all available height of the screen,once there's no more space it will show scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully by doing an update, it will work for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/api/somedata',
    success : function(data){
       $('#my-ul').empty();     //clear old data.
       _.each(data, function(myItem){
          $('#my-ul').append('<li>'+myItem.name+'</li>');
       });
       $('#your-id').perfectScrollbar('update');
    }
});
```